# TypeError: processor is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

When I'm building my Angular 11 app, I'm getting this error :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: processor is not a function
```

After digging a bit more in the logs, this is the problem :

```
[error] TypeError: processor is not a function
   at cssnanoPlugin (<project_path>/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/cssnano/dist/index.js:129:32)
```

Could someone help me on this ?

Comment: try deleting your node_modules folder and run `npm install` again

Comment: do what @Manish said, but also delete your `package-lock.json`

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:**
Make sure your postcss plugins are up to date and run:

```sh
sudo rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```

postcss-svgoIt looks like one of the cssnano plugins in cssnano-preset-default is an esmodule and resolving the module itself instead of the default export which is the processor function that is expected. I'll update this answer if I find the offending module...

**edit:** looks like the module is `postcss-colormin`

For some reason it's resolving to version 4.0.3 although postcss should automatically resolve to the newest version. Also it's resolving version 7.0.39 of postcss as a submodule??? Maybe there's a circular dependency resolve issue there.

Comment: I tried to delete my `node_modules` and my `package-lock.json` but it did not worked.

I also tried to fix the version of `postcss-colomin` to `5.0.3` in my `package-lock.json`.
Could you guide me to fix this circular dependency ?

Comment: you have a typo : `postcss-colomin` -> `postcss-colormin`. I'm assuming you typed it correctly in package-lock.json?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by setting all the dependencies versions in my package.json.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).